# OpenMapTiles-Server Web Wizard

Tags: openmaptiles

We have downloaded the Klokantech/OpenMapTiles-server and copied it to our offline computer.  We did the same thing for the MBTiles file.  When we run the command, docker run -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server, in the VM it does not find a configuration file and wants to start a web wizard.  If we browse to the wizard we are unable to move past the Styles tab.  How can we complete this step without being connected to the internet?

Comment: Maybe try tileserver-gl?

Answer (score 0):

GET https://openmaptiles.org/fonts/MuseoSans_700Web.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404

[image]

it's developers fault. they obviously use reverse proxy to github and there are problems with the project on github.
Probably a dead project.